# ngJsTree Checkbox is not visible

Tags: jstree

I use ngJSTree first time.
I cannot see checkboxes. In Browser I see style as follows when examine html element:

```
<a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="21_anchor">
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i>...
```

Controller uses checkbox plugin:

```
plugins : ['types','themes', 'checkbox'],
checkbox : {
                    "override_ui": true,
                    "real_checkboxes": true,
                    "keep_selected_style" : false,
                    "visible": true
                }
```

I use css from jstree.dist.themes.default.
JsTree should be easy to use.
Do I miss some part of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my build environment. Just add file 32px.png to the same folder as the file style.css. Then it worked.